# Performing an action on each removal and addition to a java collection

Tags: java

I can't find any information about this:

Generally I have a class extending a HashSet. Each object inserted into this collection has it's "owner" and I want to count number of objects belonging to each owner separately. So I wrote a following code:

```
public class Viruses extends HashSet<Virus> {
    private HashMap<RaceName, Integer> countsPerRace = new HashMap<RaceName, Integer>();

    @Override
    public boolean add(Virus virus) {
        if(super.add(virus)) {
            RaceName race = virus.getOwner().getRace().getName();
            if(countsPerRace.containsKey(race)) {
                countsPerRace.put(race, countsPerRace.get(race) + 1);
            } else {
                countsPerRace.put(race, 1);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object virus) {
        if(super.remove(virus)) {
            RaceName race = ((Virus)virus).getOwner().getRace().getName();
            if(countsPerRace.containsKey(race)) {
                countsPerRace.put(race, countsPerRace.get(race) - 1);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("This should not happen...");
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns number of viruses of given race.
     * @param raceId raceName of the viruses, which is equivalent of an owner id as there should never be two owners with the same race
     * @return number of viruses of given race.
     */
    public int getCount(RaceName raceId) {
        return countsPerRace.containsKey(raceId) ? countsPerRace.get(raceId) : 0;
    }

    // I don't need these, so I thought the best idea will be just to throw an exception here.
    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> collection) {
        throw new EngineRuntimeException("Unsupported operation!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Virus> collection) {
        throw new EngineRuntimeException("Unsupported operation!");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the remove method is not called, if I remove objects using an iterator. Is there a way to perform an action each time an object is added or removed from a Collection in Java? If not, which methods or classes do I exactly have to overwrite to make sure that my collection will stay consistent, no matter which way I remove or add stuff to it?

Comment: It may be easier to use composition instead of inheritance in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, there's no guarantee that the iterator uses the public `remove` method.

I would strongly encourage you to consider using composition rather than inheritance in this situation.

However, if you want to go ahead with the inheritance solution, you'd have to do something like this:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Virus> iterator() {
    final Iterator<Virus> delegate = super.iterator();
    return new Iterator<Virus>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return delegate.hasNext();
        }
        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // put your custom remove logic here
            //  ...
            delegate.remove();
        }
        @Override
        public Virus next() {
            return delegate.next();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your advice. I decided to use composition and implement Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use composition.

Create a class and implement iterable. The class will wrap a hashset and will expose add and remove method. The same remove method you can use as the iterable remove.